# Port Forwarding Windows10

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm using port forwarding to connect to a bastion host to later connect to my private network. In MacOS y did it by using

```
ssh -F /path/to/my/config/file name_of_host
```

I'm trying to do the same process in my windows machine. I have already connected to the host that I want. The problem that I'm having is that when I try to enter the webui of the name_of_host it says that page isn't working. I'm using the OpenSSL client on windows. I'm using the powershell to do the same command as I did in my mac. Also, the file that I'm using for port forwarding is something like this (config file):

```
Host bastion
 Hostname public.ip.address
 ForwardAgent no
 IdentityFile path/to/key
 User username

Host target_host
 Hostname private.ip.address
 IdentityFile path/to/key
 User username
 LocalForward port localhost:port
 ProxyJump bastion
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDIT:** The command that I'm running in powershell is `ssh -F C:\path\to\config\file name_of_host`. The error that says on chrome is "This site can’t be reached". I can reach the target node through the bastion host, but the webUI isn't loading.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the exact command you're running, and the exact error message you get back? The phrase "that page isn't working" doesn't make sense in the context of SSH, so I guess you're paraphrasing an error that you didn't understand; but somebody reading might understand it better, and be able to explain it to you.